# Транзакции в git'е

Tags: git, bat

Есть батник, который выполняет некоторый набор действий. В том числе есть коммиты в разные ветки и создание тега. Скрипт НЕ делает push.

Хотелось бы, чтобы в случае ошибки на одном из шагов все коммиты и теги созданные скриптом автоматически откатывались. Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: видимо самый простой способ - это сделать копию. Вам никто не мешает сделать локальный clone, провернуть там все изменения и если все хорошо - запушить.

Comment: @KoVadim, я и так батник локально запускаю. Просто неудобно за ним руками чистить. Какого-то более простого способа нет?

Comment: не понимаю, при чем здесь локальный запуск батника. Видимо испугались того, что нужно делать пуш?

Comment: @KoVadim, я так понимаю, ты предлагаешь при каждом запуске заново клонировать репозиторий - это долго и неудобно.

Comment: Вижу, есть недопонимания гита. В гите можно клонировать *локально* - с соседней папки (`git clone /home/test/myrep`). И пушить соответственно туда же (просто `git push --tags`). При правильном подходе локальное клонирование очень быстрое (просто скопировать файлы). А склонированную папку потом можно удалить.

Comment: @KoVadim, даже в этом варианте копирование папки `node_modules` (или выполнение команды `npm install`) займёт пару минут. Долго.

Comment: ну, так надо сразу писать что это нода. И похоже на винде. Тут выход один - страдать.

Comment: @KoVadim, а откатить всё начиная с какого-то момента нельзя? На основе reflog'а, например?

Comment: Если нужно для одной ветки - то можно использовать фишку с "savepoint" - просто создается ветка в текущем месте, потом можно коммитить/ребейзить. Если что - всегда можно откатиться к этой ветке.

Answer (score 4):

**если** изменения ограничиваются коммитами в существующие ветки и созданием меток, то можно сохранить резервную копию каталога `refs`, находящегося внутри хранилища (обычно — каталога `.git`). что-нибудь вроде:

```
$ tar -cf /путь/к/архиву .git/refs
```

в нём и сохраняются все указатели (и коммиты, на которые они указывают) — и ветки (*branches*) и метки (*tags*).

**если** же вносимые изменения затрагивают что-то более глобальное (переименование/создание/удаление веток или удалённых хранилищ, изменения в конфигурации хранилища и т.п.), то стоит сохранять и файл `config`:

```
$ tar -cf /путь/к/архиву .git/refs .git/config
```

---

для «отката» достаточно удалить этот каталог и восстановить из резервной копии. что-нибудь вроде:

```
$ rm -r .git/refs; tar -xf /путь/к/архиву
```

а рабочую копию можно привести к нужному состоянию, как и обычно, командой `checkout`:

```
$ git checkout коммит-или-ветка-или-метка
```

---

при желании от накопившегося «мусора» локальное хранилище можно «почистить» командой `gc`:

```
$ git gc
```

Comment: плохой способ. Нужно ещё файлы внутри .git также сохранять. как минимум я бы сохранял config. Также нужно подумать о чистоте reflog. Мой способ с clone локально на порядок лучше.

Comment: @KoVadim, clone — без сомнения надёжнее. но автора вопроса, судя по комментариям, не устраивает время клонирования. // *я бы сохранял config* — излишне для отката озвученных действий (коммиты и метки).

Comment: боюсь, автор даже не тестил локальний клон. А файлы лучше бы сохранял. Сегодня он коммитит, а завтра и репу перетрет.

Answer (score 3):

Правильный, качественный способ - сделать локальный clone. Лишнего копирования при этом не должно быть

> When the repository to clone from is on a local machine, this flag bypasses the normal "Git aware" transport mechanism and clones the repository by making a copy of HEAD and everything under objects and refs directories. The files under .git/objects/ directory are hardlinked to save space when possible.

то есть, если git сможет - он сделает hardlink на `.git/objects/` - что обеспечит быстрое копирование.

Если после всех изменений нужно сделать откат - просто удаляем папку с склонированной репой. Если все ок, просто делаем `git push` и снова удаляем склонированную репу. Да, push нужно будет делать аккуратно и как минимум добавить `--tags`. Но можно применить трюк с переименованием. То есть, папку с репой удаляем, а свежосклонированную переименновываем.

Comment: Судя по тому, что тут фигурируют всякие батники, речь идёт о Windows. Действительно ли под виндой git сможет создавать жёсткие ссылки? Кажется, подобного механизма нет в ntfs.

Comment: В винде точно есть возможность создавать жесткие и символические ссылки где то ещё с 2000 версии. Вот создаст ли их git, нужно проверить.

Comment: @mymedia [там всё есть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx).